# how to remove url display while image share on google+?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Share Demo: Deferred execution with language code</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   

   
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={http://mkainfotech.com/modelstown/public//uploads/model/wall/1439355689990.jpg}" onClick="javascript:window.open(this.href,
  '', 'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=600,width=600',url=no);return false;">
  
  <img
  src="https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/gplus-64.png" alt="Share on Google+"/></a>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
  <head>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```
    <title>Demo: Explicit render of a embedded post</title>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com" />
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
    </script>
    <script>

      function renderWidget() {
        gapi.post.render("widget-div", {'href' : 'https://plus.google.com/109813896768294978296/posts/hdbPtrsqMXQ'} );
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onClick="renderWidget();">Render the embedded post</a>
    <div id="widget-div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

how to remove url link display while image share..
new code to share image still showing link while image share?
how to remove url link display while image share..
new code to share image still showing link while image share?
new code to share image still showing link while image share?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `history.replaceState()` or `history.pushState()` to change the current URL without changing the current page. Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) page for a Summary. Keep in mind that only some of these APIs are supported in all browsers. Checkout [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=history) page on caniuse to see which ones are supported.

Comment: still i am sharing image with it url. how to share just image not url.